# Find deeply nested input by jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
    <div id="customerServices">
      <div id="pnlCustomerServices_Container">
        <!-- and many others divs...... -->
       <div id="s1_Container">
         <div id="ext-gen32">
           <!-- and many others divs........ -->
          <input type="checkbox" id="s1" 
               name="s1" class=" x-form-checkbox and_many_classes.....  parent" value="s1">
             <label for="s1" class="x-form-cb-label font-bold" 
                 id="ext-gen33">Label1Text</label>
           <!-- and many others divs........ --->
           </div>
         </div>

<div id="s2_Container">
         <div id="ext-gen33">
           <!-- and many others divs........ -->
          <input type="checkbox" id="s2" 
               name="s2" class=" x-form-checkbox and_many_classes.....  parent" value="s2">
             <label for="s2" class="x-form-cb-label font-bold" 
                 id="ext-gen34">Label1Text</label>
           <!-- and many others divs........ --->
           </div>
         </div>

       </div>
    </div>
```

I want to find all  `input checkBox` (in this case `input checkBox id="s1"` and `input checkBox id="s2"`) that have the attribute class contains "parent"  **and   nested inside**  `div id="customerServices"`.

But the difficult is it's unknown how many divs are between `customerServices` and `input class = "parent"` and how many values has input's attribute class.

**update**:
some time ago I was using the following code. But it doen't work for the current task.

```
$('#customerServices input:checkbox[class="parent"]');
```

**update2:**
And one more thing. How can I find the checkBox which doesn't have attribute `class=parent`

```
 $('#customerServices  input:checkbox[class^="parent"]')
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with `$("input:checkbox.parent")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
$('.parent')
```

or

```
$('input .parent')
```

**To your update:**

```
$('#customerServices input:checkbox[class="parent"]');
```

selects the checkbox where `class` equals "parent". But your class attribute contains much more. You need:

```
$('#customerServices input:checkbox.parent');
```

**update 2:**

```
$('#customerServices input:checkbox:not(.parent)');
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to select the elements you want with

```
$("input:checkbox.parent")
```

There is  no immediately obvious reason of getting involved with the `<div id="customerServices">`, but if you want to cut down on the DOM traversal you can use the stricter

```
$("#customerServices input:checkbox.parent")
```

Finally, your previous solution of

```
$('#customerServices input:checkbox[class="parent"]')
```

does not work because it only selects elements that **only** have the `parent` class, and not those that have additional classes. Since it's very unusual to have this exact requirement (I have never seen it in the wild), IMHO a selector like this should be considered a bug (even if it works at the time when it's written).

Answer (score 3):

Your code:

```
$('#customerServices input:checkbox[class="parent"]');
```

Does not work because you're using the "[attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)" selector, which will look to match the entire value of the `class` attribute (and as you have multiple class names listed, it will look to match that entire string).

However, the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), `.`, will match an individual class name. You can therefore use the class selector, instead of the attribute selector and it should work:

```
$('#customerServices input:checkbox.parent');
```