# Check all ckeckbox within nested divs

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a been trying to allow one checkbox to check other checkboxes in multiple nested divs but it does not work. I cant find the Dom path to the check box. Here is the html:

```
<div class="box span12 " id="Clarendon_region"> 

    <div class="box-content">
        <div class="row-fluid">         
            <div class="span3 ">
                <span>
                    <div class="checker">
                        <span>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </span> Branch 115
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and here is the jquery:

```
$('span input').click(function(e){

    var elIDSplit = e.target.id.split("_");

    if(elIDSplit[0] == "chk" && elIDSplit[2] == "region") {
        //alert(e.target.id);
        status = $(e.target).attr("checked");
        if (status == undefined) {
            status = false;
        }

        $(elIDSplit[1]+"_"+elIDSplit[0]+" .box-content .row-fluid .span3 span .checker span input:checkbox.friends").attr("checked",status);

    }

});
```

UPDATE: This was solved by giving the input a class name then called using this:

```
$(".allbranches_" + elIDSplit[1]).attr('checked', status);
//does not work without this line since uniform is responsible for styling the  checkbox
$.uniform.update();
```

Comment: This would help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307137/find-deeply-nested-input-by-jquery

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132898/jquery-button-selecting-all-checkboxed-within-a-div-and-button-selecting-all-on

Answer (score 0):

You have various mistakes in your code. This line:

```
$(elIDSplit[1]+"_"+elIDSplit[0]+" .box-content .row-fluid .span3 span .checker span input:checkbox.friends").attr("checked",status);
```

should actually be (with your approach):

```
$("#" + elIDSplit[1]+"_"+elIDSplit[2]+">.box-content>.row-fluid>.span3>span>.checker>span>input:checkbox.friends").attr("checked", status);
```

It would work, provided that you add the correct `id` and `class` to your input tag, which you didn't in the code you showed here.

This is however a terrible way to select your elements (and a quite strange way of nesting them, to be honest). It would be a lot easier, for example, if you gave a meaningful id to your `input` tags and select them with something like `$("#my_input")`.

Even if you can't, there's usually no need to cascade all those selectors: you could do just

```
$("#" + elIDSplit[1]+"_"+elIDSplit[2]+">.box-content input:checkbox.friends").attr("checked", status);
```

and you would obtain the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this

```
$('#theId').find(':checkbox').atrr('checked','checked');
```

here #theId is refres to the divid in which the checkbox is residing.